# SQL name parsing

Tags: sql, parsing

I have a name field that includes father, mother, spouse, child, and sibling and I need to parse out the names into father name, mother name, spouse name, child name and sibling name fields. An example is father John smith mother Jane doe. How can I do this?

Comment: Which DBMS?  It is almost always a good idea to include that information.  AFAIK, there isn't a simple standard SQL function to do that job.  There may well be something in any given DBMS, but it is likely different from DBMS to DBMS.

Comment: You mean to say add father , mother prefix in name ?